# Count how many times a value appears in tables SQL

Tags: sql

Here's the situation:

So, in my database, a person is "responsible" for job X and "linked" to job Y. What I want is a query that returns: name of person, his ID and he number of jobs it's linked/responsible. So far I got this:

```
select id_job, count(id_job) number_jobs
from 
(
select responsible.id
from responsible
union all
select linked.id
from linked
GROUP BY id
) id_job
GROUP BY id_job
```

And it returns a table with id in the first column and number of occurrences in the second. Now, what I can't do is associate the name of person to the table. When i put that in the "select" from beginning it gives me all the possible combinations... How can I solve this? Thanks in advance!

Example data and desirable output:

```
| Person |

id | name
1  | John
2  | Francis
3  | Chuck
4  | Anthony

| Responsible  |

process_no | id
100        | 2
200        | 2
300        | 1
400        | 4

| Linked  |

process_no | id
101        | 4
201        | 1
301        | 1
401        | 2

OUTPUT:

| OUTPUT |

id | name    | number_jobs
1  | John    | 3
2  | Francis | 3
3  | Chuck   | 0
4  | Anthony | 2
```

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: Ok, will do right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
select prs.id, prs.name, count(*) from Person prs
join(select process_no, id
     from  Responsible res 
     Union all
     select process_no, id
     from  Linked  lin ) a on a.id=prs.id
group by prs.id, prs.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, name, count(process_no) FROM (
    select pr.id, pr.name, res.process_no from Person pr
        LEFT JOIN Responsible res on pr.id = res.id
UNION
    select pr.id, pr.name, lin.process_no from Person pr
        LEFT JOIN Linked lin on pr.id = lin.id) src
group by id, name
order by id
```

Query ain't tested, give it a shot, but this is the way you want to go

Comment: I tried it but it produced and empty table... What might be going wrong?

Comment: I used temp tables ... remove '#' from table names

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend aggregating each of the tables by the person and then joining the results back to the `person` table:

```
select p.*, coalesce(r.cnt, 0) + coalesce(l.cnt, 0) as numjobs
from person p left join
     (select id, count(*) as cnt
      from responsible
      group by id
     ) r
     on r.id = p.id left join
     (select id, count(*) as cnt
      from linked
      group by id
     ) l
     on l.id = p.id;
```